# Does Async.RunSynchronously method block?

Tags: f#

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.runsynchronously%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) it appears that the Async.RunSynchronously runs the async computation and awaits its result. I've also read that it's similar to await in C#. I'm curious if this blocks the thread until it's run to completion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, `Async.RunSynchronously` blocks. A simple illustration:

```
let work = async {
  printfn "Async starting"
  do! Async.Sleep(1000)
  printfn "Async done" }

printfn "Main starting"
work |> Async.RunSynchronously
printfn "Main done"
```

This will print:

```
Main starting
Async starting
Async done
Main done
```

It is roughly similar to `task.RunSynchronously` in C# - although there might be some subtle differences (the F# workflow will be executed using a thread pool while the main thread is blocked and waits for the completion while the C# equivalent might actually run the work on the current thread which is more akin to `StartImmediate` in F# - which however does not wait).