# Nested Async Contexts in F#

Tags: async-await, f#

I have to make several calls to an API over the network.

```
let RestCall1 args = async{ Thread.Sleep (1000); return args}
let RestCall2 args = async{Thread.Sleep (1000); return args}
```

I know that an async{...} context has a performance hit, so I'm trying to minimize the number of contexts I create.  Plus it's awkward to pipeline.

```
let nested4 args = async{ let! x = RestCall1 args; return args }
let nested7 args = async{ let! x = RestCall2 args; return args }

let outerAsync (args : string) =
    async {
        let args1 = args
                    |> nested1
                    |> nested2
                    |> nested3
        let! args2 = nested4 args1
        let args3 = args2
                    |> nested5
                    |> nested6
        return nested7 args3          
    }
```

Is there a way of doing it (like the sample below) without blocking the thread with RunSynch?

```
let nested4 args = RestCall1 args |> Async.RunSynchronously
let nested7 args = RestCall2 args |> Async.RunSynchronously

let outerAsync (args : string) =
    async {
        return
            args
            |> nested1
            |> nested2
            |> nested3
            |> nested4
            |> nested5
            |> nested6
            |> nested7 
    }
```

Comment: I'm realizing there is no free lunch.  The thread either blocks or switches to an async context.  Nested 4 and 7 do stuff with the API call, but I can refactor to avoid the extra async block there.  Still looking for a more graceful way to pipe tho.

Comment: For the last part you could use a library which gives you Async.map and Async.bind (e.g. http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Async/reference/fsharpx-control-asyncextensions.html). This will be purely to clean up the code though. It won't affect how it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in wanting to avoid Async.Runsynchronously, which will block (see ["Does Async.RunSynchronously block?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312750/does-async-runsynchronously-method-block)).

As TheQuickBrownFox suggests, you want a library that supplies Async.map and Async.bind. Here I have used FsToolkit.ErrorHandling:

```
  open System.Threading
  open FsToolkit.ErrorHandling

  let restCall1 args = async{ Thread.Sleep (1000); return args }
  let restCall2 args = async{ Thread.Sleep (1000); return args }

  let nested1 args = args
  let nested2 args = args
  let nested3 args = args
  let nested4 args = restCall1 args
  let nested5 args = args
  let nested6 args = args
  let nested7 args = restCall2 args

  let outerAsync (args : string) : Async<string> =
    args
    |> nested1
    |> nested2
    |> nested3
    |> nested4
    |> Async.map nested5
    |> Async.map nested6
    |> Async.bind nested7
```

Async.map takes nested5 and changes its signature from `(string -> string)` to `(Async<string> -> Async<string>)`. It is called a [functor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/22/functors/).

Async.bind takes nested7 and changes its signature from `(string -> Async<string>)` to `(Async<string> -> Async<string>)`.